# Db Error while connecting with Yii Db settings

Tags: php, yii

i am getting following error.

```
CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

and this is my Db setting,now i am new to Yii so i dont know if there are some other things that i should mention, so if there are any other do let me know i will paste them ASAP.

// This is the configuration for yiic console application.
// Any writable CConsoleApplication properties can be configured here.

```
return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'My Console Application',

    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'=>array('log'),

    // application components
    'components'=>array(
//      'db'=>array(
//          'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
//      ),
        // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database

        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),

        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: Do you have MySQL installed on your localhost? Is it running? (The file you posted is the configuration for running Yii in the *console/command prompt*. The configuration for the Yii web app is typically in `main.php`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the class:

```
'db'=>array(
            'class'=>'CDbConnection', // specify class 
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
```

Comment: Also where is your code placed? i believe its under protected/config/main.php

Comment: ah, i think i found what is missing that file is hitting some remote db all the time iw as looking for some other file named config.php

Answer (score 1):

I think mysql server is not running on your machine or the server you use.

Comment: hmm, and how to test if i am running a remote server?

Comment: i am connected VIA Xammpp on local and other apps are running fine, but this isnt

Comment: I seems that mysql is not started on your localhost. I don't use XAMPP but I know it has a control panel where you can see all processes that are running or not.